# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length') unhandledRejection

Tags: javascript, node.js

error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length') unhandledRejection

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length') unhandledRejection

my code erro

```
module.exports = {
    name: "gerenciar", 
    run: async(client, message, args,) => {
        
const embederro = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Erro - Permissão`)
        .setDescription(`Você não tem permissão para isto!`)
        .setColor(config.cor)
        .setFooter({text:`${config.nomebot} - Todos os direitos reservados.`})
                if (!message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send({ embeds: [embederro] })
      if(db.all().length == 0) return message.reply(`❌ | **Você não tem nenhum produto criado!**`).then(msg => setTimeout(() => msg.delete().catch(err => console.log(err)), 5000));
      if(!args[0]) return message.reply(`❌ | **Você não selecionou nenhum ID do produto!**`).then(msg => setTimeout(() => msg.delete().catch(err => console.log(err)), 5000));
        
      
      const adb = args[0];
      const row = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
      .addComponents(
        new Discord.MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('nomegerenciar')
            .setLabel('Nome')
            .setEmoji('<:name:1076148740362092645>')
            .setStyle('PRIMARY'),
    )
    .addComponents(
        new Discord.MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('precogerenciar')
            .setLabel('Valor')
            .setEmoji('<:sifras:1075060973074927756>')
            .setStyle('PRIMARY'),
    )
    .addComponents(
        new Discord.MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('descgerenciar')
            .setLabel('Descrição')
            .setEmoji('<:config:1076148742912221245>')
            .setStyle('PRIMARY'),
    )
    .addComponents(
        new Discord.MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('estoquegerenciar')
            .setLabel('Estoque')
            .setEmoji('<:pasta:1075834358973350008>')
            .setStyle('PRIMARY'),
    )
    .addComponents(
        new Discord.MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('deletegerenciar')
            .setLabel('Deletar')
            .setEmoji('<:lixeira:1076148748205441024>')
            .setStyle('DANGER'),
    );
        
        const msg = await message.reply({ embeds: [new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`${dbB.get(`nomebot`)} | Produto`)
            .setDescription(`\`\`\`${db.get(`${args[0]}.desc`)}\`\`\`\n✨ | **Nome:** **__${db.get(`${args[0]}.nome`)}__**\n | **Preço:** **__R$${db.get(`${args[0]}.preco`)}__**\n | **Estoque:** **__${db.get(`${args[0]}.conta`).length}__**`)
            .setColor(`${dbB.get(`cor`)}`)
            .setFooter({text:"Para comprar clique no botão abaixo."})
            .setImage(`${dbB.get(`imagem`)}`)], components: [row]})
        const interação = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({ componentType: "BUTTON", })
        interação.on("collect", async (interaction) => {
         if (message.author.id != interaction.user.id) {
          return;
         }
```

I'm trying to send a command to manage, in a sales bot, but it gives this error.
someone help me fix it please

Comment: More of the error message could be helpful. This error means one of your arrays is not an array, but is instead `null`. If this is not an issue, you could consider using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining): `myArray?.length`.

Comment: Log, Your db.all() methods return value. I think it returns the null, that's because it throws  "can't read properties of null (reading length)". To avoid this use a question mark (?) before the length property db.all()?.length, that might fix this issue.